# Dynamic update to tableau

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I currently connecting dynamodb with redshift and data can be displayed on tableau.
How can I do the automatic update the graph in tableau when a record on dynamodb is added or updated?
since now i appied the
copy 
from 'dynamodb://'
iam_role
readratio 40;
however, the record seems not going to replace the previous but just duplicate the previous one.

Comment: I have to drop the table and copy a new table again in order to update it but it is troblesome.

Comment: Does your Tableau data source have an extract associated with it? Or is it a live data source? (Extracts are essentially cached copies of query results)

Comment: yes, it have an extract on dynamodb but it just copy again all the data from dynamodb database not an update

Comment: What happens when you refresh the extract?

Comment: i used the copy command to copy table info from dynamodb to redshift